# Keep NumLock always on

Tags: keyboard, numlock

I have a standard keyboard with numerical keys on the right side (I guess it's called 104-key keyboard). I want to use the numerical keys only as numerical keys. That means I don't want the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> to switch on and off the numerical keys.

However, sometimes it happens (I don't know how, perhaps by me accidentally hitting the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key) that the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is turned off, and I have to press it again. This is extremely annoying.

Is it possible to disable switching off <kbd>NumLock</kbd>?

In other words: **I want my numerical keys to always act as number keys, and to disable the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> switch**.

I am using Debian and LXDE (Openbox).

## UPDATE:

I have been using now for several years the solution, where I use  in Openbox to execute a script when <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key is pressed. This script then turns <kbd>NumLock</kbd> on again.

```
<keybind key="Num_Lock">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>numlock-on.sh</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

apart from being a dirty hack, this does not work reliably. Somehow, still it happens to me that the <kbd>numlock</kbd> key gets disabled on my keyboard.

I am frustrated with the idea of a numlock key. The concept of <kbd>numlock</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> are pure evil.

Anyway, I tried the second solution, where I put the following into my `openbox` autostart script:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'
```

but this does not work at all.

First, when I log in to `openbox`, everything works fine, and the numerical keys work as numerical keys.

But when I press <kbd>numlock</kbd>, it not only disables the numerical keys, but when I press <kbd>7</kbd> for example, I get `OH`, and then the numerical keys serve as arrow keys.

Pressing <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key again does not enable numerical keys. I have to log out and log back in again.

So the `xmodmap` solution did not work as expected.

**How can I once and for all disable completely the *satanic* feature of <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key?**

Comment: There is this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138114

Comment: @MartinVegter Would you like to post here the contents of `~/.config/openbox/autostart` and `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`?

Comment: Need an event, which will trigger the Numlock off again if it detected that numlock is ON. Disabling numlock is as easy as mentioned by `xmodmap`. Only question left is how to get that event......?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have actually been able to solve this once and for all with another way:

There is a whole thread about this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147817/104270

But actually it is as easy as calling:

```sh
# the program `numlockx`  is from the package `numlockx`
# the program `setxkbmap` is from the package `x11-xkb-utils`

numlockx on
setxkbmap -option numpad:mac
```

after your GUI login. I myself am using it, and it's working flawlessly.

Comment: Logitech G413 SE keyboard, Arch Linux XFCE: `setxkbmap -option numpad:mac` worked (`setxkbmap -option numpad:pc` to reverse; see https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config#Options-Compatibility_options). I tried the `xmodmap -e "keycode 77 ="` (noted `xmodmap -e "keycode 77 ="` output first, so I could reverse); it worked, but also killed my `Alt-Tab` (switch applications) keypress.

Comment: `numpad:mac` worked perfectly! I has having a serious problem when I put `numlockx on` in a quick loop to grant I would not turn it off for too long while playing games (when I miss click numlock key), but that makes the X server or the WM freeze for 1s ever 5to15s, I thought I was having a problem with my HD or Videocard or RAM, some hardware problem, etc. But was numlockx called wrongly, so often that way. I wanted  to comment this in case someone  makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 16):

> perhaps by me accidentally hitting the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key

If the keyboard is yours (rather than your employer's for example), just [remove it from the keyboard](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001241.htm) physically.

You can still press it with a pointy thing if you ever really need to.

[image]

Comment: how an advice to break your keyboard for this takes 16 upvotes ??

Answer (score 13):

[image: pic of keyboard options]with LinuxMint 17.2 and I imagine other versions of Ubuntu you can go to your KEYBOARD setting and then LAYOUTS on that page you will find a small "options" button.  
 
From there go to "misc compatibility options" and check 
"numberic keys always enter digits"

This is a lifesaver for me.  It bugs the heck out of me to type a number and be moved somewhere else on the page.  Cheers!  ;)

Comment: This can be done also from command line by `setxkbmap -option numpad:mac` or by setting `Option "XkbOptions" "numpad:mac"` in `xorg.conf`.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense but when I tried it I still have to toggle the Num Lock Key. I will just remember to press it once when my computer boots.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20, you must install gnome-tweaks then go in Keyboard / Additional layout options. It doesn't work for the dot which keeps its "delete" action with NumLock off.

Answer (score 8):

After reading all the answer here I was quite surprised to see that you can do the following.

```
<keybind key="Num_Lock">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>numlockx on</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

So every time you press <kbd>Num</kbd>, which deactivates the numlock. It will execute `numlockx on`, which reactivates numlock.

The name comes from my output of `xev` which gave me the key code 77 and the name `Num_Lock`

In @MartinVegters case he needed to wait a few seconds so the `numlockx on` definitely gets executed after the event of <kbd>Num</kbd> is handled.
Since there is a race condition between the handling of numlock in the kernel and the execution `numlockx`.

For this case you can write a small script `denumlock.sh` like

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep "$1"
numlockx on
```

and use it in the Key binding

```
<command>/bin/sh denumlock.sh 1</command>
```

This is dirty  but it works.

What I recommend is the following which I couldn't test myself.
You better follow the first answers which suggest to use

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'
```

But for LXDE you need to use the LXDE autostart mechanism which is different from the Openbox way of editing the `~/.config/openbox/autostart`.

In LXDE you apparently need to edit `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` or with Lubuntu `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`, which holds the commands for the start up. (See [Arch docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Autostart_programs) and [LXDE docs](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart)) You may need to create that file and add this line.

```
@xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'
```

Sadly, as I said I cannot test if this works, since I only have a VM running with LXDE.

Comment: I have tried your solution `<keybind key="Num_Lock">` but unfortunately it does not work. While the command `numlockx on` gets executed, <kbd>NumLock</kbd> still retails its function as numlock. So I can still switch numlock on/off.

Comment: As to the other solution, using `xmodmap`, when I tried the solution suggested by Risto Salminen, the command worked, but I have lost all my key bindings.

Comment: @MartinVegter Mhh you could try a `sleep 3; numlockx on` for the key bind. For the second solution have you tried it with the autostart?

Comment: I don't understand why, but even `sleep 3; /usr/bin/numlockx on` does not work. `NumLock` still acts as a on/off switch.

Comment: @MartinVegter does `/usr/bin/numlockx on` work on your system?

Comment: - yes, `/usr/bin/numlockx on` works in the terminal.

Comment: What is the name of the key you get when you use `xev` and press numlock? NumLock or Num_Lock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15301/discussion-between-raphael-ahrens-and-martin-vegter).

Answer (score 6):

On my laptop keyboard (Ubuntu 10.04) keyboard lock is currently On.

```
$ xmodmap -pke|grep 77
keycode  77 = Num_Lock Pointer_EnableKeys Num_Lock Pointer_EnableKeys
keycode 177 = XF86Phone NoSymbol XF86Phone
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 77 ="
```

Voila ! numlock is now disabled.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  77 = Num_Lock Pointer_EnableKeys Num_Lock Pointer_EnableKeys"
```

Puts it back again. (Maybe greping for Num_lock would have been a better idea, but you get the gist).

Reply to @Martin Vegter's comment.

**Ok**, in reply to your comment xmodmap ruins your bindings, understood.

I have just checked the [Openbox Documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings#Syntax)

Take a look in ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml

`ls -l lxde-rc.xml` (do you have an rc.xml as well ?, please check ).

take a copy of it as backup

(use an editor) search for numlock (maybe nmlk).

Do you see something like this ?

```
<keybind key="Numlock">
<action name="whatEverItSays"/>
</keybind>
```

Comment it out OR change The keybind key-value to an alternative eg Alt-Numlock to toggle

```
key="A-Numlock"
```

Eg

To *Comment out*

```
<!-Commented out from here
    <keybind key="Numlock">
    <action name="whatEverItSays"/>
    </keybind>
To Here -->
```

or

Change to Alt+Numlock toggle

```
<keybind key="A-Numlock">
  <action name="whatEverItSays"/>
</keybind>
```

save changes and logout/login or restart.

Comment: The problem is, any `xmodmap` command (i.e. `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'`) destroys my existing key-bindings which are defined in `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

Comment: I have replied above to obtain better formatting.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, in my `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`, there is no line containing `Numlock` or `Num_Lock`. When I create one, it has no effect: <keybind key="Num_Lock"> <action name="Execute"> <command>/bin/true</command> </action> </keybind>

Comment: There must be another config file being read before the one in your home directory. two places I suggest looking, /etc/xdg/openbox and  /usr/share/... If this is no help, I'll need to give up - sorry.

Comment: from 3.4.7 changed log (openbox) "Fix key bindings getting lost if multiple bindings at the same level could not be translated (Fixes VMWare causing Openbox keybindings to stop working)"

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the NumLock key mapping by mapping it to nothing: first run `xev` and press Num Lock (it will probably print 77), and then run the command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = """
```

where # is the keycode of NumLock.

You'd also put this to `~/.xprofile` to disable NumLock in x sessions.

Comment: In case my original question is not clear: I don't want to turn off numlock. I want the opposite. I want to ensure that it cannot be turned off (I want numlock always on)

Comment: Ah, I obviously had an error in my thinking, thanks for letting me know. :) I'll see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: this has no effect on my system: `xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Num_Lock"`

Comment: Now the command works, but it destroys all my key-bindings. All key-bindings stop working.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't, according to [this answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/71634/218718).

Comment: The problem is, any `xmodmap` command (i.e. `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'`) destroys my existing key-bindings which are defined in `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

Comment: @Risto Salminen You just repeated what I had written, seems pointless to me and more hassle for Martin, marking down!

Comment: @XTian Thanks for your critic, I think you're right. I rolled back to the older version of the answer.

Comment: I've rolled back the markdown.

Answer (score 4):

Find your numlock keycode with `xev`. For example, here, Num_Lock is 77.

Use xmodmap to remap the keycode:

- For current X sessions, inside a shell, use `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = '`.
- To all future X sessions, inside `~/.xprofile` place `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = '`.

  EDIT: Note: Doesn't work if a software is changing the Num Lock state.

Comment: The command `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = '` works, but it causes a serious problem: all my key-bindings stop working

Comment: Well, you can attempt to map it to a valid, harmless key. Like `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'` (YMMV, ESC seems safe for me).
Do you have a ~/.Xmodmap file? If yes, instead of `~/.xprofile`, place the `keycode 77 = Escape` at the end of this file.

Comment: The problem is, any `xmodmap` command (i.e. `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Escape'`) destroys my existing key-bindings which are defined in `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

Answer (score 4):

Other answers here suggested using `numlockx on` with `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 ='`, but `numlockx on` wouldn't work on my system together with that `xmodmap` command, showing me an error message:

```
$ numlockx on
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  132 (XTEST)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (X_XTestFakeInput)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

And also setting `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 ='` would for some reason remove all my keybindings made with `xbindkeys`.

[This answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1003985/267356) has helped me, however. Part of my `~/.xinitrc`:

```
numlockx on
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol Num_Lock'
```

This way the NumLock does nothing by itself, but if pressed with Shift it serves its original (mostly useless) purpose, and most importantly it doesn't prevent `numlockx on` from working on my system, or mess up my `xbindkeys` key bindings.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working off of the assumption that "always on" means "ALWAYS ON!"

I'm also assuming that Num Lock is just as annoying in text mode as it is in graphical mode ...because it is.

If building kernels is your jam, and you don't want to pry the physical cap off of your keyboard, then here is the best solution that I have found...

[Jaskaran Veer Singh | Disable Numlock Permanently through the Linux Kernel](https://jvsg.github.io/blog/2018/disable-numlock/)

To summarize, in case the link breaks, etc.:

Browse the Kernel source to this file and open it in `vim` (because all other text editors are useless):

```
./drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c
```

Locate the function:

```
static void k_pad(struct vc_data *vc, unsigned char value, char up_flag)
```

Locate the `if` statement:

```
if (!vc_kbd_led(kbd, VC_NUMLOCK))
```

And comment (or remove) the whole block:

```
/*
if (!vc_kbd_led(kbd, VC_NUMLOCK)) {

    switch (value) {
    case KVAL(K_PCOMMA):
    case KVAL(K_PDOT):
        k_fn(vc, KVAL(K_REMOVE), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P0):
        k_fn(vc, KVAL(K_INSERT), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P1):
        k_fn(vc, KVAL(K_SELECT), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P2):
        k_cur(vc, KVAL(K_DOWN), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P3):
        k_fn(vc, KVAL(K_PGDN), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P4):
        k_cur(vc, KVAL(K_LEFT), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P6):
        k_cur(vc, KVAL(K_RIGHT), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P7):
        k_fn(vc, KVAL(K_FIND), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P8):
        k_cur(vc, KVAL(K_UP), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P9):
        k_fn(vc, KVAL(K_PGUP), 0);
        return;
    case KVAL(K_P5):
        applkey(vc, 'G', vc_kbd_mode(kbd, VC_APPLIC));
        return;
    }
}
*/
```

...save, build, install, boot, profit, and enjoy!

Edit: I thought I should verify this works on my current system... while it does in text mode, in graphical mode it does not. I expect this could have something to do with the Xorg driver... anyway, as mentioned in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238785/430794), adding this to xorg.conf solves it:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Keyboard Defaults"
    Option      "XkbOptions" "numpad:mac"
EndSection
```

...and so the final result is perpetual Num Lock goodness.

Comment: - adding `Section "InputClass"` to my `xorg.conf` alone does not have any effect. Do I need to patch the kernel also? It is not clear to me whether patching the kernel is only needed for console (text mode) or whether it is needed for the  `Section "InputClass"` to work.

Comment: It's possible that another config section is overriding it, either in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, or a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, or elsewhere provided by your distribution. The kernel modification is not required for this to only work in Xorg.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you want to disable the <kbd>numlock</kbd> key disable permanently. You can do so by modifying your current keymap file by modifying the keycode 77.

Set this value to "none", so that accidental press the key will do nothing.

Use `numlockx` at bootup to start it and use the modified keymap file in one of starting script e.g. `~/.bashrc` or in `/etc/profile`.

**NOTE:** I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

On OpenSuse 13.x with KDE, this worked for me:

- install numlockx
- Add Custom Shortcut:

  - Custom Shortcuts -> Edit -> New ->  Global Shortcut -> Command/URL:
  - Action Name: NumLockOn
  - Comment: Keep numlock on
  - Trigger: set to NumLockk
  - Action-> Command/URL: sh -c 'sleep 0.5;numlockx on'
  - Hit apply
  - (done)

If NumLock needs to be enabled because its off, just use `% numlockx on`.

Comment: This is what I need. Working on Xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

I also want the numeric keypad number keys to always be numbers, none of the KP_... stuff.

My solution is part of my [Remapping Apple Keyboard for use with Linux](https://github.com/guivho/AppleKbdToLinux) repo.

Basically, it just remaps Num_Lock as F20, and the numbers as themselves.

This solution always provides the desired result and an extra function key as fringe benefit.

Answer (score 0):

A rather hackish workaround is to add a `cron` job that runs the following command

```
setleds +num
```

every 30 seconds or so to turn NumLock on.

**See also**

- [Enabling capslock from command line](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/09/enabling-capslock-from-command-line.html)

Comment: this is the ugliest hack I have ever seen, and besides it does not really solve the problem. If, somehow, `numlock` gets disabled, I cannot wait 15 sec for the cronjob to run, to have it enabled

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but this worked for me:

```
stdbuf -oL xinput test 11 | mawk -W interactive '$3==77 {printf "/usr/bin/numlockx on\n"}' | bash
```

Where 11 is the id of your keyboard. Do a `xinput` list to determine your keyboards id (in my case it's 11):

```
user@host:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Obviously, `numlockx` must be installed for that to work.

**Explanation:**

- `stdbuf -oL` modifies buffering operations of the output stream to line buffered
- `xinput test 11` prints the pressed keys to stdout
- `mawk -W interactive '$3==77 {printf "/usr/bin/numlockx on\n"}'` for every line that is printed and contains 77 (the numlock key), build a command `/usr/bin/numlockx on` ...
- `| bash` ... and pipe it to bash to execute it.

You can insert this oneliner in one of the desktop environments initial scripts or run it in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Create the following script and make it executable with `chmod +x <filename>`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ];then
/usr/bin/numlockx on
fi
```

Put the file path in `.config/openbox/autostart`

Or place it as a cron job that checks every couple minutes and runs the script if numlocks is off.

```
crontab -e 
*/1 * * * * <path-to-file>
```

Or just run the script in a loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
  x=0
  while [ x -eq 0 ];do
    if [ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ];then
    /usr/bin/numlockx on
    fi
  done
```

If you don't have numlockx you should be able to get it with `sudo apt-get install numlockx`

Comment: No, this is certainly not a good solution. Sorry

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: Well, because it is a very dirty workaround. It does not fix the underlying problem, it only sweeps the symptoms under the carpet.

Comment: Unfortunately, if xmodmap doesn't work, you don't really have any other options. Writing a script to check and enable numlock, isn't sweeping the problem under the rug. Think of it as a check-and-balance for fat fingering the key. There are no side effects and the script can easily be stopped/started at any time. It's really not that dirty of a workaround. I've seen much much worse done in the actual source code of programs that you use every day.

Comment: how can you be so sure, I don't have other options?