# xmodmap -e 'remove mod2 = Num_Lock' NumLock not working with Citrix Session

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-terminal, gnome-keyring, citrix

I've installed CentOS 6.5 - 32-bit and am using GNOME, connecting to a Citrix App server. While connecting, I'm not able to use the <kbd>Numlock</kbd> in the session. So from a blog I've found how to fix this usijg the following command:

```
xmodmap -e 'remove mod2 = Num_Lock'
```

After executing this command, <kbd>Numlock</kbd> works fine within the Citrix session, but the Numlock LED is no longer lighting up (on/off) when pressed.

When the session is closed, the <kbd>Numlock</kbd> continues to not work in other Linux apps until the above command is executed from a terminal.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A, it might be helpful in your situation as well: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98068/keep-numlock-always-on