# Keep NumLock always in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, numlock

I have a simple objective: **Keep NumLock always on**

[OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment): Linux Mint 17.3 / 18 Cinnamon

I found this:

[Keep NumLock always on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98068/keep-numlock-always-on)

So, I created this small script

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root      root      47 Apr 15 07:50 keep-numlock-on.sh
```

with content

```
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol'
```

and I added it to `sudo crontab -e` like this

```
@reboot /home/vlastimil/Development/bash/keep-numlock-on.sh
```

To my surprise, it does not work on reboot and I have no clue as to why.

It works if I manually call the script.

Any help appretiated.

Further attempts:

I created this file in `~/.config/autostart`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 308 Apr 15 10:00 NumLock.desktop
```

with content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Keep NumLock always on
GenericName=Keep NumLock always on
Comment=Keep NumLock always on
Exec=/home/vlastimil/Development/bash/keep-numlock-always-on.sh
Icon=
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

while renaming the script and changing rights to

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vlastimil vlastimil 47 Apr 15 09:56 keep-numlock-always-on.sh
```

in order to rule out permission issue.

Well, I don't know what I did wrong, but it still does not work :(

**EDIT1:**

As for the comments, I changed the contents of the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/numlockx on
DISPLAY=":0" xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol'
```

But without luck. This is really annoying to me. Please help and if you solve it, you will be rewarded with 50 points. Thank you.

**EDIT2:**

```
sudoedit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

and placed the path to the file in there, still no luck.

```
. /etc/X11/Xsession
/home/vlastimil/Development/bash/keep-numlock-always-on.sh
```

**EDIT3:**

`xmodmap` messes up with my keyboard mappings, making it unusable for this purpose.

Comment: If you manually run the cron job does it work?  I am too rusty and do not have the time to look into it but I would guess it has to do with the job setup or privileges

Comment: What if you change the content of `keep-numlock-on.sh` to `touch ~/text.txt`  Does it create the file?  I am just checking to see if it is getting called and something is failing inside or if just isnt getting called at boot.  I don't man I am sorry.  I can't sleep, I shouldnt even be on here right now

Comment: Not the best way to do it. `xmodmap` works only with X11 running so your cron might try to call it before X11 is running. Use `numlockx`, either have it called from your login manager or have it in your `.config/autostart`. For the console,  use `setleds`. You can read: [Activating Numlock on Bootup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Activating_Numlock_on_Bootup)

Comment: Well we eliminated the cron issues.  I think cylgalad is on the right track.  It is something internal.  Narrows it down a lot.  Good night and good luck

Comment: I'd remove `Terminal=true`, although it's probably irrelevant in autostart anyway (I'm no expert either, however).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Xfce: I wanted mouse emulation not to expire.

What worked:

- launch the script via autostart (like you do)
- put `sleep 5s` at the start of the script (increase "5s" if necessary)

Rationale:

If your script works when launched manually, it is not guilty. So the Desktop Environment must be overriding your settings, typically it will apply its configured keyboard map. Hence, launching your script from `crontab` or `.xinitrc` will not work. Using the Autostart feature is more reliable, but there is a question: Will the Desktop Environment apply its settings before or after launching your script? That's why `sleep` is required.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, since a delay for keymap changes is often needed. OP could also use the `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0` line and change 0 to 30, for example.

Comment: @L.Levrel Please see the new thread, where we have solved it finally (I will accept the best answer in 2 days from now): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301846/what-is-the-most-cpu-efficient-way-to-ensure-that-numlock-is-on