# Ubuntu, disable "num lock" on startup using crontab

Tags: cron, xmodmap, numlock

When I type this in a terminal I can disable the "num lock"

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

Now I want to disable it on startup. I type,

```
sudo crontab -e
```

It opens a nano page in which I type

```
@reboot ~/.xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

Or

```
@reboot xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

But neither one works. what is the problem here?

Comment: You can't easily run X11 applications from cron.  See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display

Comment: I read that page, I do not understand what they are talking about. What are the steps of the hard way to disable the "num lock"?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock Useful read to enable/disable numlock at Ubuntus at various levels. Also I don't think `cron` should be involved at all.

Comment: More pointers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98068/keep-numlock-always-on (it should be fairly easy to invert the sense of the request in that question to "always off").

Comment: I read that page. "Always on" means disable. The most liked answer is to physically remove the num_lock key from the keyboard. lol. The other solutions are calling something after I log in which is something that I do. I found a solution which was turning the num lock on every 5 second which looks stupid to me. there should be a better way.

My Ubuntu does not have "keyboard preference" (or Settings > Keyboard Layout > Options > Miscellaneous compatibility options) so I could not use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock.